# why this change signatures of java class

Tags: java, android

I have Fragments call CategoryFragments where I am adding a list name catList for that I define the variable in Class name CategoryMODEL and variable are

```
public class CategoryModel {
    private String docID;
    private String name;
    private int noOfTests;

    public CategoryModel() {
        this.docID = docID;
        this.name = name;
        this.noOfTests = noOfTests;
    }

    public String getDocID() {
        return docID;
    }

    public void setDocID(String docID) {
        this.docID = docID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNoOfTests() {
        return noOfTests;
    }

    public void setNoOfTests(int noOfTests) {
        this.noOfTests = noOfTests;
    }
}
```

but when I try to use add item in my `catLIst` I get error that **Change Signature of CategoryModel**

[image: you can see my screen]

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that the three `com.example.scorer` packages might be mucking with something. Of course, your "fixed" constructor just sets the fields to themselves, it doesn't actually change anything. That said you've got a type mismatch, so if it can't find the constructor it's probably finding a different class than you think (or your cache is out of date)

Comment: you can see both directories of CategoryModel and Fragment are same if they got mismatch how I  find this

Comment: to be honest - rename the packages. Have them have meaning (e.g. `...test`, `...answer`, `...work`)

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an empty constructor but inside your are init the values with themself, so create a constructor with params:

```
public CategoryModel(String docId, String name, int noOfTests) {
  // Init your scope variables
}
```